# Play Framework 2.6 Java Async Session and HTTPExecutionContext

Tags: java, caching, playframework

I'm using Play 2.6.3 and I have recently upgraded from Play 2.5.x.
I am having issues with `session` and `HTTPExecutionContext` for manipulating cache as the new Play 2.6.x uses `EhCache`.

In Play 2.5 it was pretty simple to getOrUpdate cache the following  way :

```
User currentUser = cache.getOrElse(session("email"), () -> {
            User user = User.find.byId(session("email"));
            cache.set(user.email, user, Constants.CACHE_TIMEOUT);
            return user;
        });
```

This doesn't works in play as they have deprecated the getOrElse method and instead have create getOrElseUpdate which uses cache API & is defined by the AsyncCacheApi and SyncCacheApi interfaces.
So, in short the new cache return CompletionStage instead of directly returning T.

the new play 2.6 code:

```
CompletionStage<User> maybeCached = cache.getOrElseUpdate(session("email"), () -> lookUpUser());

    return maybeCached.thenApplyAsync(op -> {
        return ok(views.html.dashboard.render("Dashboard", op, op.organization));
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());

public CompletionStage<User> lookUpUser() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> User.find.byId(session("email")),httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

The lookUpUser function throws an error of : `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the execution context injected into the Controller:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaAsync#Using-HttpExecutionContext

```
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class MyController extends Controller {

    private HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext;

    @Inject
    public MyController(HttpExecutionContext ec) {
        this.httpExecutionContext = ec;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
        // Use a different task with explicit EC
        return calculateResponse().thenApplyAsync(answer -> {
            // uses Http.Context
            ctx().flash().put("info", "Response updated!");
            return ok("answer was " + answer);
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

    private static CompletionStage<String> calculateResponse() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("42");
    }
}
```

So check if your `httpExecutionContext` exactly the one was injected into the controller as `HttpExecutionContext`.

Comment: Sorry for not posting my complete controller code. But I have already injected and initialized HTTPExecution context and Cache in controller

Comment: And as I am using session in my `lookUpUser` function, it just throws `No HTTP Execution Context Available`